# xsl-fo: new line not rendered for word document

Tags: scala, pdf, ms-word, xsl-fo

I am working on a piece of code(scala) which renders documents like PDF, word etc. using XSL-FO.

At a point in implementation, a new line is introduced using \n. During debugging , I see that resulting xml string is as:

```
<fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
</fo:inline>
```

But this is respected only for PDFs, and for word documents no new line is introduced.
How to get it working for word too?

Comment: I would not use fo:inline but rather fo:block. It is not clear what code you are using to do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White-space characters generally collapse and linefeeds are generally ignored.

To preserve linefeeds, add either `wrap="pre"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#white-space) or `linefeed-treatment="preserve"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#linefeed-treatment).

`wrap` is a shorthand that sets values for `linefeed-treatment`, `white-space-collapse`, `white-space-treatment`, and `wrap-option`.

---

Your other option is to generate `<fo:block />`, as @kevin-brown suggested (and as I only just saw).